# Why isn't FindMinimum doing anything?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Why is FindMinimum not giving me a result?

```
gau[x_, v_] := Exp[-(x^2)/(2*v)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*v];
mu = {-3, -2, -1, 7, 8};
n = Length[mu];
f[x_, v_] := Sum[gau[x - mu[[k]], v[[k]]], {k, 1, n}]/n;
penalty[q_?ListQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, Exp[q]]*Log[f[x, Exp[q]]]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] - NIntegrate[f[x, Exp[q]]*Log[f[x, Exp[q]]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]^2;
Table[penalty[RandomReal[.05, n]], {i, 1, 10}]
FindMinimum[penalty[q], {q, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}];

(* {0.471693, 0.473139, 0.471163, 0.472572, 0.471434, 0.472167, 0.473303, 0.467417, 0.472596, 0.47062}

FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances *)
```

The random sample results show that the penalty[] function can be decreased further, but FindMinimum doesn't even seem to be trying.

Answer (score 4):

`Method -> "PrincipalAxis"` gives a result:

> {0.236921, {q -> {-2.27053, -1.95057, -2.27053, -2.30068, -2.30068}}}

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html)

> Direct search methods which do not require derivatives can be helpful in these cases

This also means [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) might be a good option.

Comment: Sometimes I think there should be Method->TryThemAll ツ

Comment: @JohnDoty   Either that or error messages that convey some useful information.